# Which level of the logger is appropriate to ask the user to enter an input in java?

Tags: java

I would like to ask the user to enter an access token, however I cannot use `System.out.println()`, but I should use a logger instead. I'm using the class `java.util.logging.Logger`.

When I use the logger I have to specify a level, but which level is more appropriate to use?

I have done this:

```
myLogger.log(Level.INFO,"Insert the token");
String token = null;
token = variable.readLine();
```

but i'm not sure that `Level.INFO` is the appropriate level.

Here [levels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html) you can find the description for each level, but I don't know how to make a decision, do you think "CONFIG" is okay?

Comment: No, don't use logging for this. User input/output is user input/output and should have separate "its own" API, and `System.in`/`System.out` is just fine if your code is designed to work in terminal. Note that logging is designed mostly for debugging/diagnostics purposes, and can be disabled entirely. Would you like to mute any prompts to user? I don't think so.

Comment: *however I cannot use `System.out.println()`, but I should use a logger instead*: is this for homework? Because, as fluffy says, it doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: None; that's not a logging message, that's a UX message. If it's part of some sort of exercise/assignment, it's a non-sensical one--the assignment should be "instrument your code with a logger, using various levels" and using said logger approriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO logging is the wrong approach here.

a logging framework is here to for logs and abstracts the output, it doesn't guarantee you that your corresponding log is redirected to STDOUT (it depends on the configuration)

Having user interactions is a valid case to work with System.out and System.in.

Comment: i will change my code then... the problem is that i need to have 0 code smells on sonarcloud and the usage of System.out is not allowed (it causes a code smell)